# I get no exception from Hibernate and yet there is no data insertion in the table

Tags: java, hibernate

My code goes in like this:-

```
Session session = HibeSessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();

try {
    respMap = insertGradePlanMap(gradePlanSet, session); /* inside this method, I have my 
    session.save(grade) statement */
    txn.commit();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    txn.rollback();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

My insertGradePlanMap() method is :-

```
  public Map<String, String> insertGradePlanMap(Set<GradePlan> gradePlanSet, Session session) {
        Map<String, String> respMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<GradePlan> existingGradePlanList = null;
        try {
            existingGradePlanList = getExistingGradePlanMap(gradePlanSet, session);

        Set<GradePlan> inputSet = new HashSet<GradePlan>(gradePlanSet); 
        if(session != null && inputSet != null && !inputSet.isEmpty()) {
            if(existingGradePlanList != null && !existingGradePlanList.isEmpty()) {
                inputSet.removeAll(existingGradePlanList);
            }
            // add new grade plan map to school_lesson_plan_map
            if(inputSet != null && !inputSet.isEmpty()) {
                inputSet.forEach(gradePlan -> session.save(gradePlan));
            }
        }

        respMap.put(ReminderConstants.GRADE_PLAN_INSERT, ReminderConstants.SUCCESS);
        respMap.put("message", ReminderConstants.SUCCESS);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        log.error("Inserting the topic-subtopic map given in the input failed with cause ",ex);
        respMap.put(ReminderConstants.GRADE_PLAN_INSERT, ReminderConstants.FAILURE);
        respMap.put("message", ReminderConstants.FAILURE);
    }


    return respMap;
}
```

Everything goes well and txn.commit() also happens (while debugging), but there is no data insertion. In my other handler file, I can insert data into 8 tables, but in this handler file, insertion into the 9th table fails without any exception.

Comment: Show us your `insertGradePlanMap()` method

Comment: "fails without any exception" how do you know that if you catch the exception and ignore it? Try printing it out.

Comment: https://imgur.com/1jwbmSa - inputSet at line 154 has two objects that I want to insert. It's not null or empty

Comment: @Amongalen I have a log statement in the actual code. Also I debugged through the code.

Comment: You should have added it to your question directly as code and not a image.

Comment: I've edited the question with insertGradePlanMap()